# Is "revolutions" being used correctly in the following case?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> The doll fell inside the washing machine, becoming trapped in its
>   continuous **revolutions**.

(Here revolutions means the number of "spinnings" that the washing machine has.)

Is this usage correct? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: Context is everything. As long as washing machines are better know for spinning than overthrowing governments, very few people will misunderstand your sentence.

Comment: @oerkelens  You mean it's not rebelling against the cruel oppression of the overlords of the laundromat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use of the word **revolutions** is correct. As oerlekens points out, the alternative meaning is excluded by the context. **Cycles** or **cycling** are possible alternatives.

The meaning of the sentence using **in** is that the doll became part of the cycling motion. Assuming the doll is passive, this is probably what you intended. If you intended that an active doll could not get out (this could be a fantasy story) it might be better to say *trapped **by** its continuous revolutions*.